# Sorting MYSQL results by categories using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Here's the thing.  I'm trying to sort my Comics collection.  So far, I have two tables, one for the titles and type of comics (ID, prefix, title, type) and another one with individual information for each issue (ID, title, volume, issue number, value).

First thing I do is associate the title from the issues with the appropriate titles from the title table.

I do something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM comics, comicstitles WHERE comics.comTitle = comicstitles.titID ORDER BY comicstitles.titTitle ASC
```

What I get is a neat bunch of rows that I organize, and I get results like:

```
<table class='simple-list'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Volume</th>
        <th>Issue</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Alpha Flight</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$4.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alpha Flight</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>$3.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Machine Man</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$2.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Wolverine</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>$35.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Wolverine</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$60.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The X-Men</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>115</td>
        <td>$100.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The X-Men</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>116</td>
        <td>$100.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The X-Men</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>111</td>
        <td>$100.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The X-Men</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>114</td>
        <td>$100.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The X-Men</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>109</td>
        <td>$160.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The X-Men</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>112</td>
        <td>$100.00</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'><h3>Total: $764.00</h3></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Now, what I would like to do is a foreach, which would give me something like:

For each title, print the title once and all the individual issues underneath.

I would end up with something like:

```
TITLE
Issue number
Cover
Issue number
Cover

TITLE
Issue number
Cover

TITLE
Issue number
Cover
Issue number
Cover
Issue number
Cover
Issue number
Cover
```

I tried looking over and over, but I always end up on Wordpress, Joomla or Drupal sites.

And any other results is either WAY too abstract or uses numbers.

Comment: You should narrow down your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily group the items visually by title by keeping track of the title and comparing it to the current one.

Something like (simple example):

```
// before your loop
$title = '';

  // in your loop
  if ($row['title'] === $title) {
    // title already shown, do nothing or echo an &nbsp;
  } else {
    // new title, set and print it
    $title = $row['title'];
    echo htmlspecialchars($title);
  }
```

You don't mention covers anywhere, so it's impossible to help with that until you've tried it, show the code and what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches for what you are trying to do. One approach is you also read the comic-id and then you "for-each" the result and put them in an array with the ID as Array-Index.

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
    $arr[$row['titID']][] = $row;
```

If you do NOT have the need for further use of the data, you could just do

```
$active_id = $titID;
foreach ...
    //if the current eached title-id has changed (not = $active_id)
    //then set $active_id = new-title-id and start a new row
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have an array in which each title has an array for itself.

```
$titles = array();
while ($row == $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  if (array_key_exists($row['Title'], $titles)) {
    array_push($titles[$row['Title']], $row);
  }
  else {
    $titles[$row['Title']] = array($row);
  }
}
foreach ($titles as $title=>$rows) {
  echo $title . '<br>';
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['IssueNumber'] . '<br>' . $row['Cover'] . '<br>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Thomas, I feel like we're REALLY close!  I just can't get it to work, I guess it's because of the fields name, so I included two screen captures from actual tables with content: 
http://imgur.com/a/DMQBT

Comment: So you have already tried to use your actual field names? Shouldn't be hard to figure out...

Answer (score 0):

```
//Database Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 

//Database selection
mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error()); 

//your query
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comics, comicstitles WHERE comics.comTitle = comicstitles.titID ORDER BY comicstitles.titTitle ASC") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

$temp_title="";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{        
    $temp_title = $info['comicstitles'];
    if(($temp_title == $info['comicstitles']))
    {         
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td>".$info[comics]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<tr>"
        echo "<td>".$info[comicstitles]."</td>"
        echo "</tr>"
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td>".$info[comics]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";   
    }

}
```